# Set timezone for TextClock with RemoteViews

Tags: android, timezone, remoteview

I develop a widget app. Each widget has a `TextClock`, and I want to set time zone for each textclock but `RemoteViews` do not support setting the time zone.

How I can set the time zone?

Answer (score 5):

Using the `setString` method of `RemoteViews`, you are able to call `TextClock`'s `setTimeZone` method. For example:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.appwidget);
views.setString(R.id.textClock, "setTimeZone", "Europe/Zurich");
```

This assumes that the `R.layout.appwidget` layout contains a `TestClock` view with an id of `R.id.textClock`.